# Can we convert x509 structure format to x509 cerificate in .PEM format?

Tags: c

I am trying to get the peer certificate and updating the received certificate into `X509` structure as follows:

```
X509 * cert = NULL;
cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
```

Is it possible to convert the `X509` structure format to x509 certificate .PEM format?

Comment: What is `'C'` language? I only know C language (It's a name, not a `'name'`)

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is

```
int PEM_write_X509(FILE *fp, X509 *x);
```

function in

> openssl/pem.h

It saves the certificate to open file.